# iOS Separate resources files, codes for different access

Tags: ios

Currently, I am developing for enterprise app. After user login, group A will have full access and will use all resources (image, audio, etc). For group B, they will have limited access.

Problem is if I combine those 2 together in 1 app, group B app size will be bigger (than necessary one). If I totally separate 2 different app, I need to maintain same view, code, resources for 2 different app. Is there any other option to satisfy these cases?

1) Small file size, code for group B 
2) Maintainable code

Comment: Why not try [On-Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

Comment: the best way could be to use the same Xcode project, but then to export 2 different targets, and add the resources file to the single targets, so each app will share the code but won't have unused files

Comment: @Vin Thanks. Will try that also.

Comment: @meronix Thanks. I forgot about that one. If I have target for iPhone and iPad separately, 
1) Do i need to upload to app store 2 times ? 
2) If user download app from iPhone, will iPad automatically install iPad version?

Comment: there will be a different app for each target